# Searchbox with hint and search icon on left

Tags: android, searchview

I want to to create a **searchview** which should have a search icon and **hint** (as in EditText) . The default searchview in android has only the search icon . It does not have hint like edittext.

I am able to add hint to **searchview** but it is only visible after clicking on the search icon on the search-view . I am using the following code to add hint to the search-view .

```
String locationSearchViewSetQueryHint = "<font color = #ffffff>Location</font>" 
     locationSearchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml(locationSearchViewSetQueryHint))
```

How can I show the hint with search icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/search_icon">
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me give a try,

```
 <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/sv_full_list_symbols"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"                   
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:queryHint="@string/R471"                  
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" >
            </SearchView>
```

Add this in your code,

```
fullSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_full_list_symbols);
    SearchManager searchManager1 =  (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    fullSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager1.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    fullSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Happy Coding...