# How to change title in search box?

Tags: java, android, search

I tried to add android:title="" 
that doesn't work.

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) miFind.getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("your message");

didn't work as well.
[image]

```
private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onSearch() {
        return new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                WebView mWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com" +query);
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32064877/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/33250875/1531971

Comment: Did you change `miFind` to your menu item's id?

Comment: thanks for answer, how to change (search for) text after user hit search?

Comment: @jowan see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined in your menu an item with this attribute:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

then you must get it in code in order to change its hint.

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, add this code after you inflate the menu:

```
MenuItem miFind = menu.findItem(R.id.miFind);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) miFind.getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("your message");
```

replace `miFind` with the id of the menu item which acts as your `SearchView`.  
**Edit**: In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` add this listener:

```
miFind.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
     @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
          searchView.setQueryHint("your message when expanded");
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
           searchView.setQueryHint("your message when collapseded");
           return true;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the search hint, you need use this method from `SearchView`: **setQueryHint**

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html#setQueryHint(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> Sets the hint text to display in the query text field. This overrides
>   any hint specified in the SearchableInfo.
>
> This value may be specified as an empty string to prevent any query
>   hint from being displayed.

---

**Example:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
            app:searchHintIcon="@null"
            app:searchIcon="@null"
            app:queryBackground="@null"
            app:submitBackground="@null"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Java:**

```
final SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setQueryHint("Your search string");
```